# URL Rewrite doesn't work

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Could you tell me why this rewrite do not pass 2nd value? tt value is passed in to %1 but name is not in to %2

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wedding-hair-and-make-up-images-([^/]*)-(.*)\.php$ franchisee-gallery.php?franchise_name=$1&id_tt=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD|TRACE)\ /franchisee-gallery.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name=([^\&]*) 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tt=(.*) 
RewriteRule ^franchisee-gallery.php$ wedding-hair-and-make-up-images-%1-%2.php? [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The %N refeers to the matching groups of last condition, so %1 is the match of condition:
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tt=(.*)

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond

**RewriteCond backreferences: These are backreferences of the form %N (1 <= N <= 9), which provide access to the grouped parts (again, in parentheses) of the pattern, from the last matched RewriteCond in the current set of conditions.**

For your case, you could rewrite the access of "franchisee-gallery.php" to another PHP, that makes the redirection ( via HTTP Header *Location* ). I can't figure it out how to make this via Rewrite. Maybe with PERL External Rewriting Program, using RewriteMap.

---

Solution founded! Using custom environment variables, it's possible to store the matched values in temporary variables!

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wedding-hair-and-make-up-images-([^/]*)-(.*)\.php$ franchisee-gallery.php?franchise_name=$1&id_tt=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/franchisee-gallery.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name=([^&]*)
RewriteRule .* - [E=name:%1]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/franchisee-gallery.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tt=([^&]*)
RewriteRule .* - [E=tt:%1]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD|TRACE)\ /franchisee-gallery.php
RewriteRule ^franchisee-gallery.php$ wedding-hair-and-make-up-images-%{ENV:name}-%{ENV:tt}.php? [R,L]
```

Comment: it doesnt work. I have got in return URL : wedding-hair-and-make-up-images-Patsy-31.php?franchise_name=Patsy&id_tt=31

Comment: Yes, I miss the ? at the end of Rule, to clean the QueryString

Comment: very happy to accept that answer but can after I have added ? have got 500 error

Comment: where exactly shall I add that ?

Comment: now is: Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.

Comment: I can see you ? Have got mine one in the same place

Comment: Right! It makes a loop. Create a condition now, please can you test?